# Angular $HTTP returns 404 in PhoneGap (works in browser)

Tags: angularjs, cors, phonegap-build

I am trying to do a login in an Angular app packaged as using PhoneGap Build.

When I run the app in a browser it all works fine and can login using API call to remote server (so no server CORS issues).

When I try to use the same code in a PhoneGap app I get 404 response from server

PhoneGap Request/Response

```
Request URL:http://budget.expectbrilliant.com/auth/local
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found404 Not Found
Request Payload
{"email":"ben@cogiva.com","password":"nebjam2n"}
Response Headers
Client-Via:shouldInterceptRequest
```

Browser Request/Response:

```
Request URL:http://budget.expectbrilliant.com/auth/local
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:46.101.93.76:80

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:184
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 16 Jan 2016 12:50:08 GMT
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:Express
Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1Njg3ZGVkNDExNDZjODhhMDc0ZjRjMjYiLCJpYXQiOjE0NTI5NDg1OTcsImV4cCI6MTQ1Mjk2NjU5N30.cJfVi4YED2qTdE_vlaMacK9-OzCa8s2jN3BtMk2VNIA
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:48
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Host:budget.expectbrilliant.com
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2)         AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36

Request Payload
{email: "ben@cogiva.com", password: "nebjam2n"}
email: "ben@cogiva.com"
password: "nebjam2n"
```

This is the HTTP call:

```
  login: function(user, callback) {
    var cb = callback || angular.noop;
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post($rootScope.globalURL + '/auth/local', {
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    }).
    success(function(data) {
      $cookieStore.put('token', data.token);
      currentUser = User.get();
      deferred.resolve(data);
      return cb();
    }).
    error(function(err) {
      this.logout();
      deferred.reject(err);
      return cb(err);
    }.bind(this));

    return deferred.promise;
  },
```

I've tried the solutions suggested elsewhere, but can't get any response other than 404.

**EDIT**

This my first PhoneGap app and I am using PhoneGap Build. I am initially targeting Android 4.4 and up (but want a release for iOS eventually).

Any ideas?

Comment: did you whitelist the domain in phonegap?

Comment: It shouldn't need it.  I have opened the api to all domains.  It works from localhost:9000 fine.

Comment: The Cordova docs say "Cordova's default security policy allows access to any site.'

Comment: @BenDrury You are reading some old documentation. Is this your first App?  What is your target platform and their target versions? Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Once you have answer the question **in the post**, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post. FWIW: you likely need to add the *whitelist* plugin TIA Jesse

Comment: Updated post with answers.